# Nested radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to do something which isn't that complicated, after at least 4 hours of research I'm starting to think Ruby isn't so magic ...

I've got a nested form linked with models. There's a "answers" table which belongs to a "questions" table. The answers got a "name" and a "correct" field (bool). Now i've got a form and

This is inside a loop (HAML) :

`= builder.radio_button :correct, true`

So it generates one radio button per field that users can fill. It works and it fills the "correct" field in the "answers" table (which is "builder" here)

The fact is radio buttons work with the "name" HTML attribute which is also used by RoR to link everything with models. I wanted to make only one radio button group and it ends up with one group per radio button ...

Illustration:

[image]

So i started to try things like

`= builder.radio_button :correct, true, :name => "answers[correct]"`

Now the problem isn't the HTML, because buttons are from one group. RoR don't understand how to link it with the models anymore ... Is there any solution to make a radio button group and do not lose the "smart" system which link everything with the models ?

Another illustration :

[image]

Thanks, it's been a while i'm searching ...

Comment: What does `params` look like when the form is submitted? `answers[correct]` as the name for the button looks a little suspicious to me. Seems like it should be something like `answers[][correct]` or `answers[(some index here)][correct]`

Comment: I inspected the params and got the idea I explained below thank to you :)

Answer (score 0):

So there's no way to do it automatically with the RoR system, but I got one good solution about it.

I changed my code this way in the view (HAML) :

```
= answer.label :correct, "It's the correct answer", :value => answer.options[:child_index]
= answer.radio_button :correct, answer.options[:child_index], name: "question[answers_attributes][correct]"
```

And in my question_controller I simply put this :

```
right_answer = params[:question][:answers_attributes][:correct]
params[:question][:answers_attributes][right_answer][:correct] = true

params[:question][:answers_attributes].delete :correct
```

It get the correct params and transfert it within the correct one after the loop. Works like a charm. If anyone got a problem with nested radio button groups here's a solution :)